# Laravel Eloquent ORM - how to save multiple instances in a single function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a simple private messages program that sends messages to other users. They can send the message to more than just one person, as is the case with ordinary email. However, when I loop over the recipients to add a the message to the database for each, its only saving one of them.

Do I need create a new instance of the Message Model for each loop?

MessagesController:

```
public function store() {

    // Validate the message data
    if( ! $this->isValid(Input::all(), $this->message))
        return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($this->message->inputErrors);

    if( ! $this->message->sendMessage(Input::all())) {
        //log error to logger
        $errorNum =  $this->logger->createLog('MessagesController', 'store', 'Failed to add message to DB.', Request::url(), Request::path(), 8);
        Session::put('adminDangerAlert', 'Error #'. $errorNum . ' - Something went wrong attempting to save the message to the database. Contact an administrator if this continues.');
        return Redirect::back()->withInput();
    }

    Session::put('adminSuccessAlert', 'Message sent.');
    return Redirect::to('admin/messages');
}
```

Message Model:

```
public function sendMessage($input) {

    $string = App::make('StringClass');

    for($i = 0; $i < count($input['recipients']); $i++) {
        //save new message to DB
        $this->sender           = intval(Auth::id());
        $this->recipient        = intval($input['recipients'][$i]);
        $this->subject          = $string->nullifyAndStripTags($input['subject']);
        $this->body             = $string->nullifyAndStripTags($input['body'], '<b><p><br><a><h1><h2><h3><h4><h5><h6><i><blockquote><u><ul><ol><li>');
        $this->save();
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Ideally, the recursion should happen in a controller.

Comment: @AliGajani Tried that too. Still only adding 1 message to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Message@sendMessage` method is recursively updating the same exact model, not creating new models.

As [Ali Gajani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1239189/ali-gajani) has said, this is better done in a Controller. You didn't provide your attempt at doing this in the controller, but the same issue was probably happening there as well.

Here's what your `MessagesController@store` method should look like (untested):

```
public function store() {
    $input = Input:all();

    // Validate the message data
    if( ! $this->isValid($input, $this->message))
        return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($this->message->inputErrors);

    $string = App::make('StringClass');

    for($i = 0; $i < count($input['recipients']); $i++) {
        // save new message to DB
        $message = $this->message->create(array(
            'sender'    => intval(Auth::id()),
            'recipient' => intval($input['recipients'][$i]),
            'subject'   => $string->nullifyAndStripTags($input['subject']),
            'body'      => $string->nullifyAndStripTags($input['body'], '<b><p><br><a><h1><h2><h3><h4><h5><h6><i><blockquote><u><ul><ol><li>')
        ));

        // You can now access the newly created message in this iteration
        // via $message.
        // If it wasn't created, $message->exists will be false. 
    }

    Session::put('adminSuccessAlert', 'Message sent.');
    return Redirect::to('admin/messages');
}
```

Now we're recursively creating using `Message@create` rather than just updating the same model's properties.

I didn't incorporate the error check that would return `Failed to add message to DB.` since `Message@sendMessage` was always returning true anyhow, but you could fairly easily  incorporate a transaction to ensure all messages send or no messages send.